# Postgresql json_each equivalent in Presto

Tags: postgresql, presto

I have data which I used to extract from Postgresql using json_each(x), I am looking for an equivalent of json_each in Presto after a database migration to extract my data into multiple rows. The original format is as such 
{"0":100.0,"57000":75.0,"47000":80.0}

Expected Output to separate key and values into 2 columns of multiple rows

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by combining the [Trino (formerly PrestoSQL) JSON functions](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html) with [`UNNEST`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest).  The steps are:

1. Parse the raw JSON into a JSON type with [`json_parse`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse)
2. Cast from JSON to a map with a [JSON cast expression](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#cast-from-json)
3. Unnest the map into rows with the SQL standard [`UNNEST` table function](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest)

Here is a query with your example data:

```sql
WITH t AS (SELECT '{"0":100.0,"57000":75.0,"47000":80.0}' AS raw_json)
SELECT key, value
FROM
    t,
    UNNEST(
        CAST(json_parse(raw_json) AS map(integer, double))
    ) x(key, value)
```

For future reference, all of the functions are described here: https://trino.io/docs/current/functions.html